# Семантические ошибки

Tags: грамотная-речь, типы-ошибок

В интернете встретил упражнение.
Исправьте высказывания, в которых нарушена логика изложения или логика рассуждения. Определите тип ошибки.

**Детство Леонида Леонтьевича было полуголодным, наполненным тяготами войны, к счастью, в детстве он много и жадно читал.**

Ясное дело, что нарушена логика изложения. Но как исправить? Может, так?

**Несмотря на то, что детство Леонида Леонтьевича было полуголодным, наполненным тяготами войны, он много читал.**

Или, может быть, ошибка во второй части: *к счастью, в детстве он много и жадно читал?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Вариант редактирования:**

*Детство Леонида Леонтьевича было полуголодным, наполненным тяготами войны, переносить которые, к счастью, помогало то, что он тогда  много и жадно читал.*

Answer (score 4):

Если говорить об ошибках, то они никак не семантические, а логические. Существует четыре основных закона логики:

1. Закон тождества,
2. Закон противоречия,
3. Закон исключения третьего,
4. Закон достаточного основания.

*Детство Леонида Леонтьевича было полуголодным, наполненным тяготами войны, к счастью, в детстве он много и жадно читал.*

Это нарушение закона тождества: предмет мысли на протяжении всего высказывания должен оставаться неизменным. Здесь же  говорящий незаметно для себя изменяет тему и начинает говорить о другом: тема тягот войны в одном ряду с радостями.

Кроме того, имеется один из частных случаев логических ошибок - амфиболия. Амфиболия (от греч. ἀμφιβολία – двусмысленность, неясность) – двусмысленность, получающаяся от того или иного **расположения слов** или от употребления их в различных смыслах, смешение понятий. В данном примере вводное слово ***к счастью*** находится сразу после перечисления трудностей.

http://velikayakultura.ru/kultura-rechi-russkiy-yazyk/logichnost-rechi-vidyi-logicheskih-oshibok

С обоими вариантами редактирования согласна.

Answer (score 3):

Детство Леонида Леонтьевича было полуголодным, наполненным тяготами войны,  но скрашивало их то, что он тогда много и жадно читал.

Comment: @ Alex_ andex, к чему в вашем прмере относится метоимение "их"?

Comment: К тяготам относится.

Answer (score 1):

**Как определить вид ошибки?**

Исправьте высказывания, в которых нарушена **логика изложения или логика рассуждения**. Определите тип ошибки.

Если надо выбирать из этих двух вариантов, то нарушена **логика изложения**. Фактически два сообщения оказались **не связанными между собой, было пропущено важное звено, которое не всегда однозначно можно восстановить.**

Что хотел сказать автор? Рассуждаем так: он хотел дать оценку детству, какое оно было? Тяжелым и безрадостным, или что-то светлое в нем можно было отметить? И тогда мы понимаем, что мальчик мог не замечать трудностей или легко переносить их, потому что **его духовная жизнь была для него важнее, она, к счастью,  наполняла его светом.**

Но ведь может быть и другая трактовка (со значением уступки): *Всегда хотелось есть, но учился Леонид Ермолинский с огромным желанием.*  Мне она  кажется **менее убедительной.**  https://znanija.com/task/30735100